# How to draw multiple layers over Custom ImageView background

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I am new to android, spent whole day trying to figure this out including endless digging in this website, and still can't figure it out. So usually I don't ask questions here but decided to go for it

I am using a Custom ImageView that supports pinch-zoom from [here](https://github.com/matabii/scale-imageview-android/blob/master/src/com/matabii/dev/scaleimageview/ScaleImageView.java)

Basically after I load the view with my background image (a map), I want to have a red dot/cross to mark the center of the screen. Then I want the user to press a button, and mark the current place with some special mark (e.g. small circle/rectangle). Thus I want to allow all the places the user pressed a button on when pointed at the center of the imageview to be marked (and stay like this). Here's an example of how it may [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO8Q2.jpg)

I am using the custom ImageView in my main activity(works well)

As advised I've overridden the onDraw method of my custom ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);       
    canvas.drawCircle(mWidth/2,  mHeight/2, 2, paint);
}
```

And that created indeed the red(this was my paint style) circle. But now I can't come up with the method to draw the other circles. I tried to follow some advices to recreate each time the Bitmap, set the image to it, then draw whatever and set it on a canvas but that doesn't work because the coordinates of the center have changed already - the center is dynamic(and perhaps for other reasons too - Maybe The marked places should be on a different layer)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so you need your dots there? and you want to move this image around? Are these dots always on a same position on the bitmap image, not ImageView

Comment: yes once drawn they should be constant on the background image, but the image itself is dynamic on the screen

Comment: then create background bitmap from your background resource, create canvas on it, and on that canvas draw your points, after that on your on draw method paint that bitmap on ImageViews canvas an there you go. If you need samples just ask.

Comment: Yeah if you could give me some samples it would be great
What I'm missing is how to draw the points on the canvas of the background image. The canvas I am getting in the onDraw(Canvas) method is not the same one of the background image, cause thats the one I drew my center point on and it moved with me and didn't stay constant on the image. So how do I access the layer of the background image and using what methods/practices?